# How can I show weeks of years in gantt chart report in ssrs?

Tags: reporting-services, gant

[image]

Hi,

I have a problem in gantt chart report. the area I selected with blue(this a gantt chart(range bar)), I want to see the weeks of that years.
the area I selected with red (this a gantt chart(range bar)) I want to see the years of weeks.

the area I selected with orange, I get minimum value from start date column, max value from due date in horizontal axis properties

[image]

the progbar this a gantt chartt(range bar)

https://pnarayanaswamy.blogspot.com/2012/12/ssrs-2008-r2-range-bar-chart-gantt.html